# How to replace Unicode characters in the following scenario using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to replace Unicode characters in the following scenario using javascript?
Using javascript I want to replace Unicode characters with a wrapper according to their style. If possible include a range of Unicode characters([a-z]) in regex for styles other than regular.

- input = `abc`
- expected ouput = `<span class="regular>abc</span><i> </i><b></b><b><i></i></b>`

```js
text = 'abc';
text = text.replace(/([a-z]+)/,'<span class="regular">$1</span>');
text = text.replace(/([ℎ]+)/,'<i>$1</i>');
text = text.replace(/([]+)/,'<b>$1</b>');
text = text.replace(/([]+)/,'<b><i>$1</i></b>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just a matter of finding the Unicode ranges you want to replace, and [normalizing (decomposing)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) the string:

```js
let text = 'abc';
text = text.replace(/[\u{1d41a}-\u{1d433}]+/gu, s => `<b>${s.normalize('NFKD')}</b>`);
text = text.replace(/[\u{1d44e}-\u{1d467}]+/gu, s => `<i>${s.normalize('NFKD')}</i>`);
text = text.replace(/[\u{1d482}-\u{1d49b}]+/gu, s => `<b><i>${s.normalize('NFKD')}</i></b>`);

console.log(text);
```

Comment: It works fine, Thank you very much. Simultaneously can I change the characters to equivalent ASCII characters like <span class="regular>abc</span><i>uvxx</i><b>abcd</b><b><i>fghi</i></b>.

Comment: My solution does that. It's what the `s.normalize('NFKD')` is for.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. One more doubt How to retain those characters after wrapping the tags.

Comment: Retain the stylized characters? Instead of `${s.normalize('NFKD')}`, just use `${s}`.